# Minimum number of steps required to reach the last index

Tags: arrays, algorithm, dynamic-programming

Given an array of non-negative integers, you are initially positioned at the first index of the array.

Each element in the array represents your maximum jump length at that position.

Your goal is to reach the last index in the minimum number of jumps.

For example:
Given array `A = [2,3,1,1,4]`

The minimum number of jumps to reach the last index is 2. (Jump 1 step from index 0 to 1, then 3 steps to the last index.)

I have built a dp[] array from left to right such that dp[i] indicates the minimum number of jumps needed to reach arr[i] from arr[0]. Finally, we return dp[n-1].

Worst case time complexity of my code is `O(n^2)`.

Can this be done in a better time complexity.

**This question is copied from leetcode.**

Comment: The approach that you've described has a time complexity of O(n). Why do you say that it's O(n^2)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int jump(vector<int>& a) {
    int i,j,k,n,jumps,ladder,stairs;
    n = a.size();
    if(n==0 || n==1)return 0;
    jumps = 1, ladder = stairs = a[0];
    for(i = 1; i<n; i++){
        if(i + a[i] > ladder)
        ladder = i+a[i];
        stairs --;
        if(stairs + i >= n-1)
        return jumps;
        if(stairs == 0){
            jumps++;
            stairs = ladder - i;
        }
    }
    return jumps;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a range-minimum segment tree to solve this problem. A segment tree is a data structure which allows you to maintain an array of values and also query aggregate operations on subsegments of the array. More information can be found here: https://cses.fi/book/book.pdf (section 9.3)

You will store values `d[i]` in the segment tree, `d[i]` is the minimum number of steps needed to reach the last index if you start from index `i`. Clearly, `d[n-1] = 0`. In general:

`d[i] = 1 + min(d[i+1], ..., d[min(n-1, i+a[i])])`,

so you can find all the values in `d` by computing them backwards, updating the segment tree after each step. The final solution is `d[0]`. Since both updates and queries on segment trees work in O(log n), the whole algorithm works in O(n log n).

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can boost computing the dynamic with these technique:
You spend O(N) for compute current d[i]. But you can keep a set with d[j], 
where j = 0..i - 1. And now all you need to use binary search to find:

such d[j], that is minimum among all(0..i-1) and from j position i-pos is reachable.

It will be **O(n * logn)** solution

Answer (score 0):

That is a simple excercise in dynamic programming. As you have tagged it already, I wonder why you're not trying to apply it.

Let `V[k]` be the minimum number of steps to get from position `k` to the end of the list `a = (a[0], a[1], ...., a[n-1])`.

Then obviously `V[n-1]=0`. Now loop backwards:

```
for(int k=n-2;k>=0;--k)
{
    int minStep = n + 1;
    for(int j=k+1;j<=std::min(n-1,k+a[k]);++j)
    {
        minStep = std::min(minStep, V[j])
    }
    V[k]= minStep + 1;
}
```

[Demo in C++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/633dbc0dbd59811d)

After the loop, which takes `O(a[0]+a[1]+...+a[n-1])` time, `V[0]` contains the minimum number of steps to reach the end of the list.

In order to find the way through the list, you can then choose the action greedily. That is, from position `k` you always go to an allowed position `l` where `V[l]` is minimal.

(Note that I've assumed *positive* entries of the list here, not non-negative ones. Possible zeros can easily be removed from the problem, as it is never optimal to go there.)

Answer (score 0):

https://leetcode.com/problems/jump-game-ii

```
class Solution {
    public int jump(int[] nums) {
        int n = nums.length;
        if(n < 2){
            return 0;
        }
        int ans = 1;

        int rightBoundaryCovered = nums[0];
        
        for(int i=1;i<n;i++){
            if(rightBoundaryCovered >= n-1){
                return ans;
            }
            int currMax = i+ nums[i];
            while(rightBoundaryCovered>=i){
                currMax = Math.max(currMax, i+nums[i]);
                i++;
            }
            //missed this decrement statement and faced multiple WA's
            i--;
            ans++;
            if(currMax>rightBoundaryCovered){
                rightBoundaryCovered = currMax;    
            }
        }
        return ans;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Java solution (From Elements of Programming Interviews):

```
public boolean canJump(int[] nums) {
    int maximumReach = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {

        // Return false if you jump more. 
        if(i > maximumReach) { return false; }

        // Logic is we need to keep checking every index the 
        // farthest we can travel
        // Update the maxReach accordingly.
        maximumReach = Math.max(i + nums[i], maximumReach);
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: This code finds *whether* you can reach the last position (returning `false` if there's a stretch of zeros or negative numbers that's too long for you to jump over); the OP is looking for the *minimum number of steps* to reach the last position (with the explicit assumption that there are no negative numbers, and seemingly with the implicit assumption that there's no stretch of zeros that's too long for you to jump over).